# How to ask about notion meaning in plural from?

Tags: grammatical-number, articles, verb-agreement, indefinite-articles

If I want to ask about some notion mentioning it in plural? Should I use "is" or "are"?

***What is coroutines?***

or

***What are coroutines?***

or better avoid such a forms and be strightforward

***What is coroutine?***

Intuitively I use "is" like it single notion which just described as word in plural form. But is there a rule for such a case? Or what the form is preferable?

Comment: Better to use 'What are coroutines?' or 'What is _a_ coroutine?'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The verb should match the noun. 'Coroutines' is plural, so the verb should be plural.

> What are coroutines?

The singular form works too, but needs the indefinite article:

> What is *a* coroutine?

Comment: I think the downvote needs an explanation.